# How to connect ot Ubuntu Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, intel, remote, rdp

I have installed the latest Ubuntu on a PC stick and will be hopefully using it as a remote computer to remotely control my astronomy equipment.

I would like to remote into this computer from a Mac or Win10 Pro. I have installed Remote Desktop applications on the Ubuntu. With the appropriate IP address found using ifconfig I am not able to make connection.

Do I need to install or activate anything else on the Ubuntu?

Thanks

Farzad

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you want a remote desktop, here is :
 - Install VNC server
 - Activate & configure it
 - Connect to with a VNC client

Install the remote desktop VNC server

```
sudo apt install vino
```

Activate it from Gnome Settings applet

```
gnome-control-center sharing
```

Configure the remote desktop feature (password & network interface)
note that 'Remote Login' is for ssh server

Connect with a VNC client
Official VNC viewer : https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't clarify that I intend to use Windows Remote Desktop from either a Windows machine, an OSX or and iOS device. I am all setup for those.

I managed to RD into UBUNTU, but now I am not able to actually log in, and I don't even know what those session options are. I think I need to first create a remote group and make myself a member of it before I cam actually get into it. I am still searching and learning.